# How can we fix this?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Please look at the deleted answer at the bottom of [How to model a mixed-integer linear programming formulation in Python using Gurobi?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/797/how-to-model-a-mixed-integer-linear-programming-formulation-in-python-using-guro). A brand new user (1 reputation point) was trying to post a reply to the answer by David M., asking a few pertinent questions (and requesting sample data), but apparently entered it as an answer to the original post. Rather than recommend moving it to the correct location, a moderator deleted it, which apparently cannot be undone. (I tried unsuccessfully to vote to undelete.)

This is a serious disservice to a new participant. Is there anything we can do to rectify the error?

Answer (score 4):

This is a mistake on my part. I had acted too rashly this morning and did not realise that the answer was in fact a reference to David M's code.

Thank you for bringing this to my attention — I have converted Jonas' post to a comment as was meant to be the case.